# 5 stars and the golden 5 stars are not together (When browsing with Internet explorer)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This is the link of my website page https://tzipor.com/short-stories

These are the screenshots of google browser and internet explorer view.

- [Google Browser View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kDXF.png)
- [Internet Explorer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM5Z0.png)

In IE the star rating does not showing properly. I am using laravel for my application. This is the code for creating that star rating:

```
@section('css')
<style>
    .star-rating, .back-stars, .front-stars {
        display: flex;
    }
    .starNovelCat .star-rating{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .star-rating {
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 1em;
       /* justify-content: center;*/
        /*margin-top: 50px;*/

    }

    .back-stars {

        position: relative;

    }
    .type3 .back-stars{
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #843a3a;
    }
    .back-stars{
        color: #333;
    }
    .front-stars {
        color: #c3912e;
    }

     .type3 .back-stars{
        color: #bb5252;
    }
     .type3 .front-stars{
        color: green;
    }
    .front-stars {

        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;

        top: 0;
    }
    .type3 .front-stars{
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #d29b09;
    }
</style>
@endsection

@if(Healper::averageRatingByStory($story->id) != false)
@php($storyAverageRating = Healper::averageRatingByStory($story->id))
@php($star = ($storyAverageRating/100)*5)
<div class="star-rating" title="{{round($star,2)}}">
    <div class="back-stars">
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>

        <div class="front-stars" style="width: {{$storyAverageRating}}%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@endif
```

Comment: Minor detail, but you appear to have a stray `;` at the very top-left of your page, above the banner.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/476)

Comment: @deceze What would be amusing (to me) is if that `;` were actually before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` causing IE to use Compatibility Mode and thus causing the break :D

Comment: I am sorry guys if my question are not appropriate or not have much explanation. If anyone need any more information, you can ask me.

Comment: If you want help, you need to explain *in the question* what the problem is, *with code.* See also the [help] and in particular the guidance for creating a [mcve].

Comment: I already explain the my problem with my description.

Comment: Probably looking at this would be a start: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: add left:0; to .front-stars class and give a try

Comment: Thank you @ChandraShekhar . left: 0 works.

Comment: @Shamim Sdr, Approve my answer. Thanks. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

add `left:0;` property to `.front-stars` class and give a try.
Hope this works..